# Did Satoshi know since its publication all the applications that the blockchain would enable?

Tags: blockchain, satoshi-nakamoto

Or he only thought about Bitcoin?

Answer (score 4):

> Did Satoshi knew since its publication all the applications that the blockchain would enable?

I doubt it. Even the phrase 'blockchain' was coined long after the [Bitcoin paper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) was published. However, Bitcoin uses primitives like HashCash to do something that their creators never envisioned, so I don't think he would be surprised by the ideas of Bitcoin being used for things that he didn't think of.

Answer (score 2):

Did Tim Berners-Lee know all the applications that HTML would enable? No, not even close. Why? Because his invention made it possible for millions of people over the past 30 years to build upon it to create breathtaking and marvelous web applications.

Like HTML, Bitcoin is merely the foundation upon which a massive structure is being built. The core technology of Bitcoin -- the blockchain -- is the key feature Satoshi was trying to build. "Bitcoin" is simply marketing... its a name. His goal was to release the Bitcoin network as a proof of concept. He knew it would have value on its own, but he also knew that, because the project being open-source, the resulting innovation was going to be beyond his ability to predict.

If you go back and read his original correspondence on the cryptography mailing list, his ideas and attitudes leaned heavily towards a Libertarian / Austrian Economics school of thought. He wanted to build something that would empower creative and talented people to use the blockchain to create breathtaking and marvelous fintech applications.

Comment: hi, do you have a url link to cryptography mailing list?